# no se ejecuta mi proyecto en html

Tags: html, c#

mi problema es que cuando ejecuto mi proyecto en visual studio 2017, aparece en el navegador hello word y no la calculadora que programé, estoy seguro que el codigo esta bien por las dudas lo muestro, probé en iniciar tro proyecto nuevo y pegarlo al codigo pero sigue en la misma.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Pagina Web SILV52 2017</title>
    <style>
        .body{
            background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/eNHFe8V.h}jpg");
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment:fixed;
        }
        </style>
    <link rel="icon" href="c:\Users\joese\Documents\Icono\superthumb.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    class="body">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function suma() {
            var num1, num2, total;
            var resul;

            num1 = number(document.getElementById("entrada1").value);
            num1 = number(document.getElementById("entrada2").value);
            total = num1 + num2;
            resul = "@ Resultado: " + total;

            document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = result;

        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .texto {
            font-size: 50px;
            color: #fbf204;
            text-align: center;
        }


        .texto2 {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 10px 470px;
            border-style: inset;
            text-align: center;
            color: #00ff21;
            padding: 35px 10px;
        }

        .texto3 {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-indent: 435px;
        }

        .texto4 {
            color #ff0000;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <p class="texto" SILV52 2017></p>
    <h2 class="texto4">Pagina simple y sencillita para todos los pelotudos</h2>
    <br />
    <p class="texto3">Ingrese Número<input type="number" id="entrada1" /> /</p>
    <p class="texto3">Ingrese Número<input type="number" id="entrada2" /> /</p>
    <style>
        .butto{
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color:white;
            padding: 10px 32px;
            text-align:center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display:inline-block;
            margin: 10px 568px;
            cursor: pointer;

        }
    </style>
    <br />
    <button class="butto" onclick="Sumnar()">Calcular</button>
    <br />
    <h2 class="texto2" id="teto"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que tipo de proyecto creaste? MVC? Sitio web?

Comment: el error estuvo en el codigo (bueno como yo lo test en visual studio 2015 y los errores estaba en el codigo

Comment: cree aspx.net ,vacio

Comment: @FacundoPaez aparte tenias errores en el codigo

Answer (score 1):

hola tu codigo deberia ser algo asi para que funcione bien:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Pagina Web SILV52 2017</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color:red;
            background-attachment:fixed;
        }
        </style>
    <link rel="icon" href="c:\Users\joese\Documents\Icono\superthumb.ico" />
</head>
<body class="body">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function suma() {
            var num1, num2,resul,total;

            // num1 = number(document.getElementById("entrada1").value);
             num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("entrada1").value);

            //num1 = number(document.getElementById("entrada2").value);
             num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("entrada2").value);

            total = num1 + num2;
            resul = " Resultado: " + total;

            document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = resul;

        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .texto {
            font-size: 50px;
            color: #fbf204;
            text-align: center;
        }


        .texto2 {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 10px 470px;
            border-style: inset;
            text-align: center;
            color: #00ff21;
            padding: 35px 10px;
        }

        .texto3 {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-indent: 435px;
        }

        .texto4 {
            color #ff0000;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <p class="texto" SILV52 2017></p>
    <h2 class="texto4">Pagina simple y sencillita para todos los pelotudos</h2>
    <br />
    <p class="texto3">Ingrese Número<input type="number" id="entrada1" /> /</p>
    <p class="texto3">Ingrese Número<input type="number" id="entrada2" /> /</p>
    <style>
        .butto{
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color:white;
            padding: 10px 32px;
            text-align:center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display:inline-block;
            margin: 10px 568px;
            cursor: pointer;

        }
    </style>
    <br />
    <button class="butto" onclick="suma()">Calcular</button>
    <br />
    <h2 class="texto2" id="texto"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

el primer error que vi y es muy obvio es como llamastes a la funcion tu lo hhicistes asi:

> ```
> <button class="butto" onclick="Sumnar()">Calcular</button>
> ```

y se supone que tu funcion se llama suma  y el otro error estaba aqui:

> ```
> <h2 class="texto2" id="teto"></h2>
> ```

te quivocastes en el ID y le pusistes teto se supone que es texto?

y el otro error fue aqui:

> ```
>         document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = result;
> ```

tu usastes result y tu la definistes como resul tu deberias usar resul y no result(auque deberia ser result) y el error mas comun es que no usastes la funcion : parseInt

para convertir texto en numero.

espero que te alla servido y ayudado :)

Comment: @Facuando si mi codigo te funciono, dale a la palomita